# Why does FINDSTR not find the searched string with space in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

So I am running a **FINDSTR** command to search a file for the text `[errorCode: 0]` and using the option `/v` to output the lines which do not contain this string. This is the used code:

```
@findstr /i /v "\[errorCode: 0\]" file1.log >>file2.txt
```

But this puts all the contents of `file1.log` to `file2.txt`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the command line `@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /C:"[errorCode: 0]" file1.log >>file2.txt` which runs explicitly a literal string search.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Just curious though, shouldn't the escape character work in the code I posted?

Comment: `/C:"string"` option ***always*** defaults to literal search, so the `/L` option is not needed. But without `/C`, the first search term in a list of space delimited search terms determines if the search is literal or regex. So without `/C` it is recommended to always use `/L` or `/R` to make the intent clear.

Comment: the "older" `find` command is sufficient here: `find /i /v "[errorCode: 0]" file1.log >>file2.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command line:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /C:"[errorCode: 0]" file1.log >>file2.txt
```

This runs explicitly a literal string search for `[errorCode: 0]` because of `/L` and `/C`.

On usage of **FINDSTR** with its regular expression support not being comparable with regular expression support in other applications and interpreters it is advisable reading its brief help by running `findstr /?` in a command prompt window and additionally also:

- **SS64** documentation for command [FINDSTR](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html).
- **SS64** additional page [FINDSTR - Escapes and Length limits](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr-escapes.html).
- [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/) written by Dave Benham on Stack Overflow.

The command line

```
@findstr /i /v "\[errorCode: 0\]" file1.log >>file2.txt
```

is not producing the expected output because a space character in a just double quoted search string is interpreted as delimiter between multiple search strings. So **FINDSTR** is searching with this command line for lines containing either the string `[errorCode:` or the string `0]` using a case-insensitive regular expression find and not for lines containing the string `[errorCode: 0]` and outputs all lines not containing either of these two strings.

This command line could be also written as:

- **Literal** instead of regular expression find searching case-insensitive for `[errorCode` **OR** `0]` in a line and output all lines not containing either of these two strings:

  ```
  @findstr /I /L /V "[errorCode 0]" file1.log
  ```
- **Literal** instead of regular expression find searching case-insensitive explicitly for `[errorCode` **OR** `0]` in a line and output all lines not containing either of these two strings:

  ```
  @findstr /I /V /C:"[errorCode:" /C:"0]" file1.log
  ```
- **Regular** expression find searching case-insensitive explicitly for `[errorCode` **OR** `0]` in a line and output all lines not containing either of these two strings:

  ```
  @findstr /I /R /V /C:"\[errorCode:" /C:"0\]" file1.log
  ```

For example `file1.log` contains:

```
Line 1: [errorCode: 0]
Line 2: [CodeError: 0]
Line 3: [errorCode: 1]
Line 4: [noErrCode: 1]
```

The output of the three command lines above and the initial command line in question is:

```
Line 4: [noErrCode: 1]
```

But the expected output for this example is:

```
Line 2: [CodeError: 0]
Line 3: [errorCode: 1]
Line 4: [noErrCode: 1]
```

This is the output on running one of the following command lines:

```
@findstr /I /V /C:"[errorCode: 0]" file1.log
@findstr /I /V /C:"\[errorCode: 0\]" file1.log
@findstr /I /L /V /C:"[errorCode: 0]" file1.log
@findstr /I /L /V /C:"\[errorCode: 0\]" file1.log
@findstr /I /R /V /C:"\[errorCode: 0\]" file1.log
```

`\` is the escape character in a literal and a regular expression string. But in a literal string only the backslash `\` itself and the double quote character `"` must be escaped with a backslash. In a regular expression string the backslash left to a character with a special regular expression meaning results in interpreting the next character as literal character.

My recommendations for usage of **FINDSTR**:

1. Specify one or more strings to **c**ompare with always with `/C:"..."` (or with `/C:...`) and never with just `"..."` to get a space in a search string always interpreted as space character.
2. Specify always `/L` for a **l**iteral or `/R` for a **r**egular expression find.

Then the find is always as expected by most users with knowledge of string searching from other applications or interpreters and not knowing the **FINDSTR** specific rules on interpreting a string to find in double quotes.